# How to Line Plot several columns in Seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn

I am exploring the [FIFA data](https://www.kaggle.com/karangadiya/fifa19/tasks?taskId=148) set.
I would like to see on a single line plot how is the `Wage` influenced by the variables listed below. How could I achieve this with seaborn?

```
Composure
Marking
Penalties
Vision
Stamina
```

Wage should be on the `Y` axis, while the other attributes should be shown on the `X` axis.
Each line on the plot should be represented by Composure, Marking..etc.

Stacking one plot over the other is not clean and I don't get the legend, so this is bad way of reporting.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(x=data.Positioning, y=data.Wage)
sns.lineplot(x=data.Overall, y=data.Wage)
sns.lineplot(x=data.Penalties, y=data.Wage)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you ask something like this?

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

columns_plot = ['Composure', 'Marking', 'Penalties', 'Vision', 'Stamina']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 9))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.EngFormatter())
for each in columns_plot:
    sns.lineplot(data = df_final, x = each, y = 'Wage', label = str(each), ci = None)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Produces:
[image]

2nd method, side by side:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 5, figsize=(23, 5), sharey=True)

columns_plot = ['Composure', 'Marking', 'Penalties', 'Vision', 'Stamina']

for i, each in enumerate(columns_plot):
    sns.lineplot(data = df_final, ax = axes[i], x = each, y = 'TransformedWage', ci = None, color = 'g')
plt.show()
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: Yes, something like this indeed. Now that I see the figure, it looks really messy, especially if I add more variables, so I am wondering, is there any better way you can advise to visualize it, perhaps several side by side line plots?

Comment: You can use subplots or PairGrid

Comment: I will look at it, but if you could update your answer with those methods, it would be really helpful for others to see other options and attract more upvotes. Many thanks.

Comment: Sure, added subplot method. I think you need another for loop if you want to divide them as rows and columns, axes will have [0,0] / [0,1] and [1,0] / [1,1] etc.

Comment: I am running your 2nd method, but I am getting only 200.000 and 400.000 on y axis.

Comment: Was it fine when you run 1st method? Did it show 100k 200k or was it the same like 200k 400k?

Comment: First method was okay. The first method was showing 100k, 200k, 300k, 400k, 500k

Comment: Sorry I have no idea about it. It might be related to yticks, if you search you can find about it I think, you need re-arrange it.